# HERE Maps crash at libMAPSJNI.so

Tags: android, crash, here-api

We used HERE Premium SDKs.
When we long-press the map, we are reversing the address of the latitude and longitude at that point using ReverseGeocodeRequest2.When the search is completed, the address is displayed on the map.

Repeated long press will cause the following crash.

I am looking for the cause of the crash

### Please let me know the steps to resolve.

> 11-29 11:44:16.227 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi W/google-breakpad: Failed to generate minidump.
>   11-29 11:44:16.284 491-491/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi.MainActivity to jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi.MainActivity#1
>   11-29 11:44:16.440 28186-28103/? A/google-breakpad: Microdump skipped (uninteresting)
>   11-29 11:44:16.484 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   11-29 11:44:16.484 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
>   11-29 11:44:16.484 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi W/google-breakpad: 70.0.3538.80
>   11-29 11:44:16.484 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi W/google-breakpad: 353808052
>   11-29 11:44:16.485 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   11-29 11:44:16.485 27937-28103/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x11 in tid 28103 (Gestures), pid 27937 (um.m2smart.navi)
>   11-29 11:44:16.562 28192-28192/? E/DEBUG: failed to readlink /proc/28103/fd/148: No such file or directory
>   11-29 11:44:16.606 28192-28192/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
>   11-29 11:44:16.612 812-812/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 28103
>   11-29 11:44:16.614 28192-28192/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 27937 (target tid = 28103)
>   11-29 11:44:16.651 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: *****               *****
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/marlin/marlin:9/PPR1.180610.009/4898911:user/release-keys'
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: pid: 27937, tid: 28103, name: Gestures  >>> jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi <<<
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x11
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000001  r1  00000005  r2  c48417b0  r3  00000001
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG:     r4  c3bdc190  r5  c0a7a620  r6  c3bdc194  r7  c3bdc194
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG:     r8  00000000  r9  00000001  r10 00000000  r11 c2e0b75c
>   11-29 11:44:16.652 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG:     ip  c48417d0  sp  c2e0b758  lr  c97c3828  pc  c97c4f9c
>   11-29 11:44:16.655 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
>   11-29 11:44:16.655 28192-28192/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0026ff9c  /data/app/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi-AWOBSvAp7UkzzwuMoCXHhw==/lib/arm/libMAPSJNI.so

Comment: Can you please provide me the SDK version and platform that is being used (Android/iOS)? Then we can have a deeper look into this topic.

Comment: We used Android, SDK  Version: 3.6.0.523
Build Date: Mon Dec 11 10:05:29 UTC 2017

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue here locally with the newest release. Can you pleas update and try it once agin?

Comment: We can reproduce  very easy,SDK version is HERE_Android_SDK_Premium_v3.9.0_99.Our device is Android 8.0.stacktrace as following.

Comment: We can provide source code to reproduce the phenomenon. Could you please confirm this? .

Comment: That would be very helpful.

Comment: I will send the source code, please let me know how to share these.E-mail?Google Drive? or other

Comment: I send source code via Google Drive.I informed URL to your boss.

Comment: Please share the link with the source code.

Comment: I already share link to your boss.And your boss response me.We will try your suggestion.

Comment: According to your team advice、we applied it as attached.
However, the phenomenon does not change and occur crash.

Please check and revert me how to fix this issue.

Comment: I checked the second amendment plan and tried it.However, the phenomenon does not change and will crash

Comment: source code can be downloaded the following link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LEHhEg-817qcKSpcxD1FoPKPcmZEZs7h

Answer (score 0):

Please download the new version 4.x now. Also refer the premium SDK download reference.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/search/ReverseGeocodeRequest.html

```
public ReverseGeocodeRequest(GeoCoordinate location,
ReverseGeocodeMode mode,
float bearing)
Creates a reverse geocode request that resolves a GeoCoordinate into an Location.
Parameters:
location - A GeoCoordinate representing the query location context.
mode - A ReverseGeocodeMode mode in which the response should be filtered.
bearing - A bearing expresses the direction in which the vehicle is heading in degrees starting at true North and continuing clockwise around the compass. Ignored if mode is not equal to ReverseGeocodeMode.TRACK_POSITION.
Throws:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Upon a failure to handle a passed argument.
```